# How to push inline-block wrapped text (after line break) to right?

Tags: html, css, layout, antd

I'm facing an issue in development of directory tree, done via `<ul>`, when text of an item exceeds the container width.

I'm using antd react library, so I don't have much flexibility in generated html markup without, modifying libraries code. However, I do have control over stylesheet.

---

Here is the html markup, of what component Antd Tree Component generates (with some modification for ease of reading):

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="myicon">
        <i aria-label="icon: down" class="anticon anticon-down ant-tree-switcher-icon"><svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" class="" data-icon="down" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><path d="M884 256h-75c-5.1 0-9.9 2.5-12.9 6.6L512 654.2 227.9 262.6c-3-4.1-7.8-6.6-12.9-6.6h-75c-6.5 0-10.3 7.4-6.5 12.7l352.6 486.1c12.8 17.6 39 17.6 51.7 0l352.6-486.1c3.9-5.3.1-12.7-6.4-12.7z"></path></svg></i> 
      </span>
      <span class="myTitle">
        <span>Compliance, objectives and functional statments</span>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is current css:

```css
#container {
  width: 260px; background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.myicon, .myTitle, ul, li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.myicon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 44px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    float:left;
}

.myTitle {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 24px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
}

li {
    white-space: break-spaces;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gLqosjmp/6/

---

**What have I tried?**

- Making `myicon` `height` absurdly large, but it impacts subsequwnt
  `<li>`
- Modifying `wrap`, and `white-space` and `display` of both classes - but I was not able to successfully get the result

---

This is what it renders:
[Current Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwIOx.png)

This is what I want to render: [Targeted Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygrse.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your text to be kept within certain boundaries, the easiest way may be to display inline elements (such as your `spans`) as a block instead of inline and manipulate their widths and heights.  Or you can just use flex, pretty straightforward, just set your `li` to `display: flex`.

You can then play around with `flex-grow` and other child properties, here is a [great flexbox reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
#container {
  width: 260px; background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.myicon, .myTitle, ul, li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.myicon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 44px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    float:left;
}

.myTitle {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 24px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
}

li {
    display: flex;
    white-space: break-spaces;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="myicon">
        <i aria-label="icon: down" class="anticon anticon-down ant-tree-switcher-icon"><svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" class="" data-icon="down" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><path d="M884 256h-75c-5.1 0-9.9 2.5-12.9 6.6L512 654.2 227.9 262.6c-3-4.1-7.8-6.6-12.9-6.6h-75c-6.5 0-10.3 7.4-6.5 12.7l352.6 486.1c12.8 17.6 39 17.6 51.7 0l352.6-486.1c3.9-5.3.1-12.7-6.4-12.7z"></path></svg></i> 
      </span>
      <span class="myTitle">
        <span>Compliance, objectives and functional statments</span>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by just adding `display: flex` to your `li`

```css
#container {
  width: 260px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.myicon,
.myTitle,
ul,
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.myicon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 44px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
}

.myTitle {
  display: inline;
  line-height: 24px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}

li {
  /*The only change*/
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="myicon">
        <i aria-label="icon: down" class="anticon anticon-down ant-tree-switcher-icon"><svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" class="" data-icon="down" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><path d="M884 256h-75c-5.1 0-9.9 2.5-12.9 6.6L512 654.2 227.9 262.6c-3-4.1-7.8-6.6-12.9-6.6h-75c-6.5 0-10.3 7.4-6.5 12.7l352.6 486.1c12.8 17.6 39 17.6 51.7 0l352.6-486.1c3.9-5.3.1-12.7-6.4-12.7z"></path></svg></i> 
      </span>
      <span class="myTitle">
        <span>Compliance, objectives and functional statments</span>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change .myTitle to inline-block and set a width to it.

```css
#container {
  width: 260px; background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.myicon, .myTitle, ul, li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.myicon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 44px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
}

.myTitle {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 24px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 210px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
}

li {
    white-space: break-spaces;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="myicon">
        <i aria-label="icon: down" class="anticon anticon-down ant-tree-switcher-icon"><svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" class="" data-icon="down" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><path d="M884 256h-75c-5.1 0-9.9 2.5-12.9 6.6L512 654.2 227.9 262.6c-3-4.1-7.8-6.6-12.9-6.6h-75c-6.5 0-10.3 7.4-6.5 12.7l352.6 486.1c12.8 17.6 39 17.6 51.7 0l352.6-486.1c3.9-5.3.1-12.7-6.4-12.7z"></path></svg></i> 
      </span>
      <span class="myTitle">
        <span>Compliance, objectives and functional statments</span>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```